# Updating a view from Django < 1.5 to Django 1.5

Tags: django, view

I'm having some trouble rewriting a view for django 1.5.

I can't use the`object_list` element, what can I use instead to achieve the same result?

This is my current view

```
def forum(request, slug):
    try:
        f = Forum.objects.for_groups(request.user.groups.all()).select_related().get(slug=slug)
    except Forum.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    form = CreateThreadForm()
    child_forums = f.child.for_groups(request.user.groups.all())
    return object_list( request,
                    queryset=f.thread_set.select_related().all(),
                    paginate_by=FORUM_PAGINATION,
                    template_object_name='thread',
                    template_name='forum/thread_list.html',
                    extra_context = {
                        'forum': f,
                        'child_forums': child_forums,
                        'form': form,
                    })
```

Comment: See this related article as a migration example: [How to migrate from function-based generic views to class-based analogs in Django](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-migrare-dalle-viste-generiche-basate-su-funzioni-alle-analoghe-basate-su-classi-in-django/).

Comment: i would like to do that with render_to_response, is it possible?